Get-Process in powershell doesn't show processes which are definitely running
I'm just getting into a Powershell. As Microsoft declares that the Powershell is a Swiss knife for windows administration etc. How it's possible, that on my local computer I'm running powershell with admin privileges and trying to get all running processes with command Get-Process The list of processes is incomplete. Tasks manager shows more processes that are running. For example the process nVision Axence Agent (it's a trusted software). I've tried to run Get-Process Axence and this returns nothing... So I'm really confused.
How to properly get all processes currently running on a local computer via Get-Process powershell cmdlet?

I saw in Task manager that this process is related on Axence DB Server (AxDBSrvrA) process, but neither of them are visible via Get-Process

Have you tried running get-process while task manager is running?  I'm thinking of the possibility that invoking task manager triggers the invocation of the Avence SW.

Get-Process will list all running processes.
Searching for processes doesnt work how you think it does though. Get-Process does allow for easy searching by using wildcards. In your case, running Get-Process *axence* will show all entries containing the string axence.
